# Connect 2 external monitors with MacBook Pro

Tags: display, macbook-pro

I recently got an MacBook Pro (Retina) 15" from my office. I prefer to use my laptop as a desktop. So I have a docking station for my Dell which I used to connect to 2 external monitors, keyboard and mouse. I use both OS X as well as Windows via Boot Camp.

Is there anything similar for new MacBook Pro (Retina)?

If not a docking station what would be better alternative to connect 2 external Dell monitors (supporting resolution of 1920 * 1080)?

Answer (score 14):

I have a MacBook Pro Retina. I connected a 27" Asus Display directly to the HDMI port, and a 27" Samsung Display to the Thunderbolt port through a DVI to VGA adapter.

I now have three displays stacked horizontally, with quite some nice real estate. Both external displays are 1920 x 1080 and have the Mac with Retina resolution of 2560 x 1600. You can do at least the same with your 15" MacBook Pro Retina.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: On my mbp late 2013 this setup also works great with windows in bootcamp: one monitor connected to thuderbolt and second one to hdmi. Tried to connect two monitors right to thunderbolts but it didnt work well.

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for a [HengeDock Retina Dock](http://hengedocks.com/preorder_HD03VA_dock.php). I have one similar, except mine is for a previous version of Macbook instead of Retina.

You can pre-order them on their site.

Answer (score 3):

If you have an Apple Thunderbolt Display, then you don't need a dock at all. You simply plug the display into one of the Thunderbolt ports of the Mac, and use the display as the dock. It has lots of ports on the back - including several USB ports, a gigabit Ethernet port, another Thunderbolt port, etc.

You can plug another Thunderbolt display (daisy-chained) into the Thunderbolt port of the display, or if you have a DVI display you can plug that into the second Thunderbolt port of the MacBook Pro with an adapter, or you could plug an HDMI monitor into the HDMI port on the right-hand side of the Mac.

You can also [daisy chain an HDMI or DVI monitor via the Thunderbolt display, but only if it goes via an additional device](http://www.macrumors.com/2011/09/16/apple-thunderbolt-display-with-multiple-monitors/).

Answer (score 1):

Belkin offer the `Thunderbolt Express Dock` which will do what you want.

http://www.belkin.com/au/p/P-F4U055/

Matrox have a similar product but it has less ports.

http://www.matrox.com/docking_station/en/ds1/

I was not able to confirm either can run two monitors but at worst you would have to plug the other monitor into the other Thunderbolt port or HDMI port on the Mac.

If you just want the two monitors then you can plug a Mini DisplayPort to DVI cable into both the Thunderbolt ports or run one monitor DVI and the other via HDMI (leaving a Thunderbolt port free).

Comment: thanks tony, Looks like Hengedock will suit my requirement.